# Smallest positive integer $n$ s.t. f(n) = $n^2 + n + 41$ is composite?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm pretty sure it's 40 but I'm not too sure if it's enough to show that:

$n(n+1) + 41$

$41(\frac{n(n+1)}{41} + 1)$

and the smallest composite no# will be achieved when n+1 = 41, n =40?

Am I missing anything here? --> Yes I still need to *show* that for n < 40, it's prime..ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What is your argument for why the smallest composite will be achieved when $n+1=41$?

Comment: I guess you want smallest **positive** $n$. It is indeed $40$, but one has to verify that everything below is prime. Not pleasant!

Comment: It's a finite number of drudgery-filled cases. Write a computer program to check it.

Comment: @anon since we want $\frac{n(n+1)}{41}$ to be the smallest possible integer

Comment: Checking modularity for each prime $p<41$?

Comment: By that reasoning, $7\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{7}+1\right)$ isn't composite until $n+1=7$. But it does happen to be composite for $n=1$.

Comment: @CarlosEugenioThompsonPinzón yeah I was thinking that too hmm

Comment: @anon interesting point! i'll have to re-think my method

Comment: Rabinowitz showed, in 1913, that $x^2+x+p$ represents the maximal number of consecutive primes if and only if $x^2+xy+py^2$ is the only (equivalence class of) positive binary quadratic form of its discriminant. This condition is called "class number one." For negative discriminants the set of such discriminants is finite, called Heegner numbers. For you, $p=41.$ see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289338/is-the-notorious-n2-n-41-prime-generator-the-last-of-its-type/289357#289357