# Prove that euler number_40 is a prime =))

Tags: number-theory

How can i prove that euler number_40 is a prime?

Euler numbers are numbers that can be written as $E_n=n^2-n+41$ where $n$ is an integer. Now i need to prove that $E_{40}$ is prime

Comment: Well, $E_{40} = 1600 - 40 + 41 = 1601$, so it's pretty small.

Comment: But how can i prove that 1601 is a prime without having to search for prime factors

Comment: You can't. To prove a number is prime, you have to check for prime factors less than or equal to its square root, so all primes up to $40$. There other ways to check whether or not a number is prime, but they are more complicated.

Comment: @Ragnar So yes, he can. Whether that would be more efficient is another question entirely.

Comment: You can prove it without factoring... much more work of course. Connected with Heegner-Stark-Baker on number fields but much easier.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stark%E2%80%93Heegner_theorem

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you don't need to factor anything. the result goes back to Rabinowitz in 1913. Eventually I proved both directions in my preferred language; see [Is the notorious $n^2 + n + 41$ prime generator the last of its type?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289338/is-the-notorious-n2-n-41-prime-generator-the-last-of-its-type/289357#289357)

Might as well throw in the quick version: given some number $q \geq 3,$ the polynomial 
$$  n^2 + n + q $$ is prime for $$  0 \leq n \leq q-2  $$ 
if and only if
$q$ is prime and $4q-1$ is prime and the class number for discriminant $1-4q$ is one. For me, this means positive binary quadratic forms, same concept for imaginary quadratic fields, as the class group and narrow class group agree.

Comment: The question has a $-$ instead of a $+$ in $n^2 - n$.

Comment: @TMM, if $f(n) = n^2 - n + 41 $ and $g(n) = n^2 + n + 41,$ then $f(n+1) = g(n).$ Also, $f(1-n) = f(n),$ so you get an artificially long string of primes by throwing in some negative $n.$