# Prove that $n^2+n+41$ is prime for $n<40$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, principal-ideal-domains

Here's a problem that showed up on an exam I took, I'm interested in seeing if there are other ways to approach it.

> Let $n\in\{0,1,...,39\}$. Prove that $n^2+n+41$ is prime.

I shall provide my own solution, though I am curious does anyone know how to do this without using PIDs?

Comment: For more information see [e.g. this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/289338/11619). Not sure if I want to call this a duplicate though?

Comment: Yeah, I read that, but it seemed to me to be a meta question about the existence of such functions that produce long strings of primes, and the comments deal with more general questions.

Comment: The Maple code $$for\, n \,to\, 40 \,do\, if \,not\,isprime(n^2+n+41) \,then \,print(n)\, end\, if\, end\, do $$ outputs $40.$

Comment: Probably relevant: [Is the notorious $n^2+n+41$ prime generator the last of its type?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289338).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since $4(n^2+n+41)=(2n+1)^2+163$, one way would be to methodically show that $-163$ is a quadratic *non*-residue mod all (odd) primes less than $41$.

**Added later**:  The OP has asked for further details, so here goes.

If $p\mid n^2+n+41$, then $(2n+1)^2+163\equiv0$ mod $p$, which means that $-163$ is a square mod $p$.  Now the values of $n^2+n+41$ for $n\lt40$ are all less than $40^2+40+41=1681$, so if any of them were composite, it would have to have a prime factor less than $\sqrt{1681}=41$.  That prime factor would have to be odd, since it's clear that $n^2+n+41$ is always odd.  This would require $-163$ to be a quadratic residue for some odd prime less than $41$.  So it suffices to compute the Legendre symbol $({-163\over p})$ for $p=3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31$, and $37$, and show that it's $-1$ in each case.

This is a bit tedious, but less so than directly checking the primality of the $39$ numbers $(1^1+1+41), (2^2+2+41),\ldots,(39^2+39+41)$.  For example,

$$\left({-163\over17}\right)=\left({7\over17}\right)=\left({17\over7}\right)=\left({3\over7}\right)=-\left({7\over3}\right)=-\left({1\over3}\right)=-1$$

where the string of equalities here makes use (twice) of the [Law of Quadratic Reciprocity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticReciprocityTheorem.html).

Comment: I can't believe my prof. marked this exercise with a 1-star (out of 3) difficulty. :(

Answer (score 15):

We will prove this using the PID $R:=\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$, where $\omega=\frac{1+i\sqrt{163}}{2}$, with the norm $N(a+b\omega)=|a+b\omega|^2=a^2+ab+41b^2$.

**Lemma 1:** If $p$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\exists n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $p|n^2+n+41$, then $p$ is reducible in $R$.

*Proof:* Let $p|n^2+n+41$ and assume $p$ is irreducible. Then $p$ is also prime, since $R$ is known to be a PID. Thus $p|(n+\omega)(n+\overline{\omega})\Rightarrow p|n+\omega$ or $p|n+\overline{\omega}$. The first is nonsense since multiples of $p$ are of the form $ap+bp\omega$ so this would force $p$ to be a unit in $\mathbb{Z}$. But the second is also impossible since $n+\overline{\omega}=n+1-\omega$.

**Lemma 2:** If $p$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}$, then $p$ is reducible in $R$ iff $\exists a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $p=a^2+ab+41b^2$

*Proof:* Let $p$ be reducible. Then $p=\alpha\beta\Rightarrow p^2=N(p)=N(\alpha\beta)=N(\alpha) N(\beta)\Rightarrow p=N\alpha=N\beta$. For the other direction, let $p=a^2+ab+41b^2$ and assume it is irreducible, so $p=(a+b\omega)(a+b\overline{\omega})$. Since $p$ is irreducible, one of these has norm $1$. But these clearly have the same norm, so then $N(p)=1$ which is impossible.

**Proof of the theorem:** Let $m=n^2+n+41$ and assume $m$ is not prime. Then there exists primes $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{m}{pq}\in\mathbb{N}$. Thus by Lemma 1, $p,q$ are reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ and so by Lemma 2 they are of the form $p=a^2+ab+41b^2$ and $q=c^2+cd+41d^2$. Notice that $b^2d^2>0$ since if $b=0$ then $p=a^2\Rightarrow p$ is not prime. Likewise for $d$. WLOG $a>0$. Then either $a^2+ab>0$, in which case we have $$pq\leq m<41^2\leq (a^2+ab+41b^2)(c^2+cd+41d^2)=pq$$ or $a<-b$, in which case we have $$41\leq a^2+40b^2\leq a^2+ab+41b^2=p$$ as neither $a$ nor $b$ can be zero.

Answer (score 13):

**Theorem** $ $ The polynomial $\rm\, f(x) = (x\!-\!\alpha)\,(x\!-\!\alpha') = x^2 + x + k\, $ assumes only prime values for $\rm\ 0 \le x \le k-2  \iff \mathbb Z[\alpha]\ $ is a PID.

**Hint** $\ (\Rightarrow)\ $ Show all primes $\rm\ p \le \sqrt{n},\; n = 1\!-\!4k\,$ have $\rm\, (n/p) = -1\, $ so no primes split/ramify.

For proofs, see e.g. Cohn, *Advanced Number Theory*, pp. 155-156, or Ribenboim, *My numbers, my friends*, 5.7 p.108.  Note: both proofs employ the bound $\rm\ p < \sqrt{n}\ $ without explicitly mentioning that this is a consequence of the Minkowski bound - presumably assuming that is obvious to the reader based upon earlier results. Thus you'll need to read the prior sections on the Minkowski bound. Compare Stewart and Tall, *Algebraic number theory and FLT*, 3ed, Theorem 10.4 p.176 where the use of the Minkowski bound is mentioned explicitly.

Alternatively see the self-contained [paper [1]](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2689515) which proceeds a bit more simply, employing Dirichlet approximation to obtain a generalization of the Euclidean algorithm  (the Dedekind-Rabinowitsch-Hasse criterion for a PID). If memory serves correct, this is close to the approach originally employed by Rabinowitsch when he first published this theorem in 1913.

[1] Daniel Fendel, [Prime-Producing Polynomials and Principal Ideal Domains,](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2689515)
Mathematics Magazine, Vol. 58, 4, 1985, 204-210

Answer (score 5):

Below is problem $\rm 6\ (B3)$ from IMO $1987$ and its solution (from [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1987_IMO_Problems/Problem_6), or [Scholes](https://prase.cz/kalva/imo/isoln/isoln876.html))

> **Theorem**. If $k^2+k+n$ is prime for all integers $k$ such that $0\le k\le \sqrt\frac{n}{3}$, then $k^2+k+n$ is prime for all integers $0\le k\le n-2$.
>
> **Proof**. First observe that if $m$ is relatively prime to $b+1$, $b+2$, $\cdots$, $2b$, then $m$ is relatively prime to any number less than $2b$. Indeed if $c\leq b$, then we can choose some $i$ to make $2^ic$ lies in range $b+1,b+2,\cdots,2b$, so $2^ic$ is relatively prime to $m$. Hence $c$ is also a prime. If we also have $(2b+1)^2>m$, then we can conclude that $m$ is a prime, otherwise there must be a factor of $m$ less than $\sqrt{m}$.
>
> Let $n=3r^2+h$ where $0\leq h<6r+3$, so $r$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $\sqrt{n/3}$. (to see this, just let $r=\lfloor\sqrt{n/3}\rfloor$, then we can write $n=3(r+\epsilon)^2(0\leq\epsilon< 1)$, so $h=6r\epsilon+3\epsilon^2\leq 6r+3$).
>
> Assume that $n+k(k+1)$ is prime for $k=1,2,3\cdots,r$. We show that $N=n+(r+s)(r+s+1)$ is prime for $s=0,1,2,\cdots,n-r-2$. By our observation above, it is sufficient to show that $(2s+2r+t)^2>N$ and $N$ is relatively prime to all of $r+s+1,r+s+2,\cdots,2r+2s$. We have $(2r+2s+1)^2=4r^2+4s^2+8rs+4r+4s+1$. Since $s,r\ge1$, we have $4s+1>s+2$, $4s^2>s^2$ and $6rs>3r$. Hence $$(2s+2r+1)^2>4r^2+2rs+s^2+7r+s+2=3r^2+6r+2+(r+s)(r+s+1)\ge N.$$ Now if $N$ has a factor which divides $2r-i$ int the range $-2s$ to $r-s-1$, then so does $N-(i+2s+1)(2r-i)=n+(r-i-s-1)(r-i-s)$ which have the form $n+s'(s'+1)$ with $s'$ in range $0$ to $r$.