# Are $n^2+n+41$ primes when $0\leq n \leq 39$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I wrote a program to check and found, when $0\leq n \leq 39$, $n^2+n+41$ are primes.

But now I wonder: does it have a simple method to **prove** when $0\leq n \leq 39$, $n^2+n+41$ are primes without **check it one by one**?

**Update:** A similar question [Prove that $n^2+n+41$ is prime for $n<40$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706565/prove-that-n2n41-is-prime-for-n40?lq=1)

Comment: I put an elementary proof of Rabinowitz(1913) at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289338/is-the-notorious-n2-n-41-prime-generator-the-last-of-its-type/289357#289357

Answer (score 3):

http://planetmath.org/proofthatn2n41isprimefor0leqnleq40

I hope that this will help you, a little bit at least.

Comment: The planetmath proof is very unsatisfactory, given the OP's request.  I suspect there is a truly elementary proof based on a clever partition of $41$ and an associated inequality.

Comment: @guest, the original proof, both directions, by Rabinowitz in 1913 amounts to this, although he wrote in number field language. I wrote both directions in quadratic forms style, see my comment directly below the question.

Comment: @WillJagy disregard my last comment, I misunderstood.  So there is no proof for the particular form that does not involve equivalence of forms?