# Ideal $\mathfrak p^i$ is not principal

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let c be a postive squarefree integer. Let $K = \mathbb Q(\sqrt{-c})$. Let $p$ be a prime that splits in $K$ and let $\mathfrak p$ be a prime ideal above $p$. I need to prove the following:

Prove that for all integers $i\geq 1$ such that $p^i <\frac{|\text{disc}( K)|}{4}$, the ideal $\mathfrak p^i$ is not principal. I have no idea where to start. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks very much for the edit.

Comment: Also - for future reference, this is a [Mathjax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thanks, I really need to learn it!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hint to start you off.

Suppose that $\mathfrak p^i = (\alpha)$ for some $\alpha\in \mathcal O_K$. Then, taking norms,  $$|N_{K/\mathbb Q}(\alpha)| = N\mathfrak p^i=p^i<\frac{|\mathrm{disc}(K)|}4.$$

But we know exactly what the norm of an element of $K$ looks like, and we know exactly what the discriminant of $K$ is (depending on $c$ modulo $4$).

---

Irrelevant remark:

Here is a cute corollary: take $c=163$. Then $K$ has class number one - i.e. every ideal of $\mathcal O_K$ is principal. It follows that no prime less than $41$ ($|\mathrm{disc}(K)| = \frac{163}4$) can split in $\mathcal O_K$.

The minimal polynomial of $\alpha = \frac{1+\sqrt{-163}}2$ is $f(X) = X^2-X+41$. The fact that every prime less than $41$ is inert in $K$ (only $163$ ramifies) shows that $f$ is irreducible modulo $p$ for all $p<41$. In particular, 
$$p\nmid f(n)\quad \forall p<41, n<41,$$
from which it follows that $f(n)$ is prime for all $0\le n<41$ (since $f(n)<41^2$ is composite iff it has a prime factor $<41$). This gives a algebraic number theoretic justification for why the polynomial $f$ [takes so many consecutive prime values](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706565/prove-that-n2n41-is-prime-for-n40?lq=1).

Comment: Where you wrote Np^i, should it be N(P^i)? i.e. the norm of P^i

Comment: Since the norm is (totally) multiplicative, both of those expressions are the same.

Answer (score 2):

First let $c\equiv 1 \pmod 4$. Here $\frac{\text{disc}(K)}{4}=c$. Suppose $\mathfrak p^i$ is principal say $(a+b\sqrt{-c})$. Then so is the other guy $(\mathfrak p^i)'=(a-b\sqrt{-c})$ lying above $p^i$. Then the norm of $\mathfrak p^i$ is $$p^i=(a+b\sqrt{-c})(a-b\sqrt{-c})=a^2+cb^2,$$ for $b\neq 0$. So $|b|\geq 1$. So $p^i=a^2+cb^2\geq cb^2\geq c=\frac{|\text{disc}(K)|}{4}$ as needed.

If $c\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ and $\mathfrak p^i$ is principal, then we compute the norm of $\mathfrak p^i$ as above: $$p^i =N (\mathfrak p^i)=(a+b\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{-c}}{2}\right))(a+b\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{-c}}{2})\right))=a^2+ab+(\frac{1+c}{4})b^2$$

As above, we can assume that $|b|\geq 1$ and by switching the sign of $b$ if necessary, we can assume that $a^2+ab$ is non-negative, so that $a^2+ab+(\frac{1+c}{4})b^2\geq \frac{c+1}{4}\geq \frac{\text{disc}(K)}{4}$ as we wanted.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Good catch, Mathmo123. :)

Comment: How did you get that p=a^2 + cb^2?

Comment: @Mathmo123 Hey, thank you for your helpful comments! I think that fixes it and makes it even simpler than before? Could you take a quick look?

Comment: Does the same method work for c congruent to 3 mod4?

Comment: @Richard See my edit.