# $n^2-79n+1601$ always a prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am struggling with proving or disproving this:

> $n^2-79n+1601$ is a prime for all natural numbers $n$ (except multiples of $1601$).

This somehow has a relation to Stanislaw Ulam spiral.

What would be a good approach?

Comment: Put $n=1601$...

Comment: I updated the question with a limitation regarding 1601. Sorry, my bad. Thanks for hint anyway!

Comment: Thanks for the hint, what would be than the explanation of long "diagonals" within ulam spiral, one of which should be reflection of the polznomial from this question?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: A guy (not you) added anothe comment, and I responded, but he now deleted his comment, thats why you dont understand...

Comment: Ah, never mind then :-)

Comment: @VividD But Aryabhata's remark also applies to $\,f(n\!+\!1) = n^2-77n+1523,\,$ i.e. put $\,n = 1523.\,$ Note $\,f(n\!+\!1)\,$ takes the same values as $\,f(n).\ \ $

Comment: @Bill Dubuque, right, that would be the most straightforward counterexample.

Comment: Is it enough to exhibit a few counterexamples or do you need a rigorous proof? If the former, you can just say 80, 81, 84, 89, 96, ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $f(n)$ be our polynomial. Note that $f(1)=1523$. I won't bother to check whether this is prime.

For $f(1+1523)$ is divisible by $1523$, and a lot bigger, so it must be composite.

**Remark:** An argument that fundamentally is the one of the answer shows that if $f(n)$ is a non-constant polynomial with integer coefficients, then $f(n)$ cannot be always prime.

Comment: Extremely suave proof and sharp idea!

Comment: @VividD Note that this is simply the method in Aryabhata's comment, but applied to $\,f(n\!+\!1) = n^2-77n+1523,\,$ i.e. put $\,n = 1523.\ $ [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/865406/242) for the general theory.

Answer (score 4):

As I thought, taking $m = x + 39,$ this is
$$  x^2 - x + 41.  $$
This sets the record for consecutive primes, $x=1,2,3,...,40.$

If $x = t+1$ we get $t^2 + t + 41.$ No important difference, This way it is primes $t=0,1,...,39,$ but divisible by $41$ for $t=40,41.$ Also a pretty good performance for $t > 40$ and $t \neq -1,0 \pmod {41},$ but nobody knows whether it (or any other one-variable polynomial) represents infinitely many primes.

See [Is the notorious $n^2 + n + 41$ prime generator the last of its type?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289338/is-the-notorious-n2-n-41-prime-generator-the-last-of-its-type/289357#289357)

Comment: This is also a magnificent fact! Why 40?? (I am just asking myself)

Comment: @VividD see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stark%E2%80%93Heegner_theorem Meanwhile, at the question I linked in my answer, i give a proof in English of the result of Rabonowitz (1913), that $n^2 + n + p$ represents primes for $n=0, 1,...,p-1$ if and only if $q = 4 p - 1$ is also prime and the binary quadratic form $x^2 + x y + p y^2$ has class number one.

Comment: Fascinating!...