# Who found the expression $n^2 - n + 41 $ for generating prime numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers, math-history

I am doing some research and I cannot seem to find the answer anywhere so does anyone know who found the expression $n^2 - n + 41 $ for generating prime numbers?

Comment: Euler, it seems.

Comment: http://eulerarchive.maa.org/pages/E461.html

Comment: This seems like it would be a good fit for [hsm.se], too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's Euler who first found it. He mentions that formula in 1771 in [a letter to Bernoulli](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~euler/docs/originals/E461.pdf). The relevant passage is shown below, in particular the second paragraph:

[image]

My translation:

> $\qquad$ The biggest prime number that we know of is without doubt $\mathfrak{2^{31}-1=2137483647}$, which Fermat assured to be prime, $\mathfrak{\&}$ I also proved that; because this formula will never admit other divisors other than one $\mathfrak{\&}$ or the other of these $\mathfrak{2}$ forms $\mathfrak{248n+1\ \& \ 248n+63}$, I have examined all prime numbers contained in these two formulas until $\mathfrak{46339}$, and none was found to be a divisor.
>
> $\qquad $ This progression $\mathfrak{41.\ 43.\ 47.\  53.\  61.\  71.\  83.\  97.\  113.\  131\ \, \& \rm c.}$ whose general term is $\mathfrak{41+  }x\mathfrak{+}xx$, is as much remarkable since the $\mathfrak{40}$ first terms are all prime numbers.

Comment: The "Nouveaux mémoires..." are not "his" work, but collected works from many authors. The quote is from a letter which appears in the 1772 volume of these "Nouveaux mémoires". See [this](https://books.google.fr/books?id=__QgAQAAMAAJ&pg=PR42#v=onepage&q&f=false) and the next page.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thanks for the correction, I'll fix that.

Comment: But whoever first published it may or may not be the first one to think of it. Who knows if maybe someone will find some ancient Chinese manuscript with this same result.

Comment: you know history of math too?

Comment: @abel Hahah, I just read up on that from time to time, particularly *Analysis by Its History* of Hairer and Wanner, and I know some French too so it's kind of an advantage, but still I'm certainly not an expert ;-)

Answer (score 3):

> Euler first noticed (in 1772) that the quadratic polynomial
>   $$
>     P(n) = n^2 + n + 41
> $$
>   is prime for all natural numbers less than 40.

from [Wiki:Formula for primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes#Prime_formulas_and_polynomial_functions)

Comment: Source ? $\;\;$

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM wiki, added...

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted, Euler, in 1772 published this result in a very similar form (see @draks... answer).

Note however, that he published the quadratic $n^2+n+41$, not $n^2-n+41$.

My contribution: 
This result was stated in Nouveaux Mémoires de l'Académie royale des Sciences. Berlin, p. 36, 1772, by L. Euler.

Answer (score 2):

Some context, the polynomial $n^2 + n + 41$ is prime for $0 \leq n \leq 39.$ It cannot possibly be prime for $n=40$ or $n=41$ because $n^2 + n + 41$ is then divisible by $41$ but larger than $41.$

It is a simple result, that $n^2 + n + k$ can only represent such a large initial sequence of primes, $0 \leq n \leq k-2,$ when both $k$ and $4k-1$ are prime. Furthermore, Rabinowitz, 1913, given those conditions, showed this happens if and only if the class number of discriminant $-(4k-1)$ is one. I give a proof of this at  [Is the notorious $n^2 + n + 41$ prime generator the last of its type?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289338/is-the-notorious-n2-n-41-prime-generator-the-last-of-its-type/289357#289357)

Later,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stark%E2%80%93Heegner_theorem
this was shown to be the last time this happens.