# A question on the prime generating polynomial $x^2 -79x+1601$.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

In Tom Apostol's book *Analytic Number Theory*, author says $x^2 -79x+1601$ gives prime numbers for $x=0,1,...,79$.

We can see this by putting values. Is there any other way of knowing this property of this expression? How can we construct more expression with this property?

Answer (score 5):

There is a good deal of repetition involved here. If we take the pure translation
$$ x = t + 40 $$ the polynomial becomes
$$ t^2 + t + 41 $$
which is prime for $0 \leq t \leq 39.$ It is also prime for $-40 \leq t \leq -1,$ however these primes are exactly the same primes as thos for non-negative $t.$

The reason we know that this polynomial ($t$) gives all those prime values is that $41$ is prime, $4 \cdot 41 - 1 = 163$ is also prime, and the positive binary quadratic form $$ x^2 + xy + 41 y^2$$ is of class number one, meaning all forms of that discriminant are ($SL_2 \mathbb Z$) equivalent to it. The basic facts here were known to Gauss, an elementary proof of if and only if was provided by Rabinowitz in 1913. See my proof at [Is the notorious $n^2 + n + 41$ prime generator the last of its type?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289338/is-the-notorious-n2-n-41-prime-generator-the-last-of-its-type/289357#289357)

For those who do not know anything about binary quadratic forms, this is a table from Rose, *A Course in Number Theory* The ordered triple $A,B,C$ refers to the (positive) quadratic form
$$ f(x,y) = A x^2 + B xy + C y^2. $$ See how there is just one entry for discriminant $-163.$

[image]

Comment: I don't know what class is. I am undergraduate .

Comment: @lowiq do you have any books, or taken any course, in beginning number theory, and either (quadratic) number fields or (integer) quadratic forms?

Comment: yes. I have read analytical number theory fairly. I have taken few lectures in algebraic number theory. But my knowledge of quadratic form is very shallow

Comment: @lowiq I added in a table with everything you need for this type of question. Rabinowitz wrote his proof in terms of algebraic number theory; this is just another way of writing.