# When $x^2+x+p$ is prime for $x=0$ to $p-2$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Is it true that $f(x)=x^2+x+p$ is prime for all $x=0,1,...,p-2$ iff $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1-4p})$ has trivial class group ?

I've heard this statement but getting no idea how to solve it, any help would be great.

Comment: Yes, this is a well-known result of Rabinowitz.  See Will Jagy's answer to a similar question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/289357/30402

Comment: See [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/865406/242)