# Quadratic Form producing primes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to make inferences about quadratic forms $f(n) = x^2+ax+b$ that produce primes for some integers $0,1,2,...$ (upto a finite limit). I noted that $f(0)$ must be prime so $b$ must be prime. Also is it necessary that $a$ should be prime or something like this $$(|a| \le 1) \vee (|b|\le 1)\vee(\text{prime}(|a|)\wedge \text{prime}(|b|))$$ 
What can we further deduce?

Comment: Here's some reading on [Prime-Generating Polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html).

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289338/is-the-notorious-n2-n-41-prime-generator-the-last-of-its-type/289357#289357