# Show that $2n^2+11$ and $2n^2+29$ generate primes for all non-negative integers $n<11$ and $n<29$ respectively

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show that $2n^2+11$ and $2n^2+29$ generate primes for all non-negative integers $n<11$ and $n<29$ respectively.

This question is from Elementary Number Theory by Kenneth Rosen. The book's solution has used a brute force method to generate all numbers and manually check if they are prime or not.

I wish to ask instead if there is a better method. I have looked around on the internet and couldn't find anything. I instead wrote a [C program](https://repl.it/@SigmaG/PrimeFormulaTester) to test the theory about primes of the form $2n^2+x$ $(0\leq n<x)$, and it seems only $x=3,5,11,29$ satisfy it under $10^6$.

So, is there no better, more number theoretical way to verify the given question?

Comment: there might be a sensible proof, not sure yet. Here is the proof for the better known $n^2 + n + 41$ http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289338/is-the-notorious-n2-n-41-prime-generator-the-last-of-its-type/289357#289357

Comment: For $2n^2+11 \leq 2\cdot 11^2 + 11 = 253$ and hence it is enough to check that $2n^2+11 \mod p \neq 0$ for $p < \sqrt{253} $. Thus we need to check for $p=2,3,5,7,11,13$. This is not hard.

Comment: ُ$x^2+x+17$, $2x^2+29$, $x^2+x+41$ and $x^2-29x+160$ are Euler numbers which give primes for 0=<n<x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Context: here is a proof for the better-known $n^2 + n + 41$ [Is the notorious $n^2 + n + 41$ prime generator the last of its type?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289338/is-the-notorious-n2-n-41-prime-generator-the-last-of-its-type/289357#289357)

Took me a while and some numerical experiments, but I got this one. For foundational material on positive binary quadratic forms, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_quadratic_form  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_quadratic_form#References  My favorite book is Buell; people seem to like Cox.

We are given a prime $p \equiv \pm 3 \pmod 8$ such that the form class number $h(-8p) = 2.$ In particular, the only classes are those of $$ x^2 + 2py^2 $$ and $$ 2 x^2 + p y^2. $$ The shorthand  for these two forms is $\langle 1,0,2p \rangle$ and $\langle 2,0,p \rangle \; . \;$

Note that the product $2p$ must be one of [Euler's Idoneal Numbers](https://oeis.org/A000926)

We will ASSUME that there is an integer $n$ with $1 \leq n < p$ such that $2n^2 + p$ is composite. We will show that this leads o a contradiction by constructing a third primitive quadratic form of the same discriminant.

Let $q$ be the smallest prime that divides any $2n^2 + p$ with $n < p.$ Usually there will be several small $n$ giving the same $q.$ In turn, take the smallest $n$ that works, meaning $2n^2 + p \equiv 0 \pmod q \; . \;$ We get $q$ prime,
$$ 2n^2 + p = q t \; , \;  $$
$$  t > q > 2n \; . \; $$

There are just two cases.

IF $q > 4 n,$ then
$$  \langle q,4n,2t \rangle    $$
is a reduced primitive form of the same discriminant $(-8p).$ It is not equivalent to either of the original forms listed, that is what we get for reduced forms.

IF $q < 4 n,$ then
$$  \langle q,4n-2q, 2t - 4n + q \rangle    $$
is a reduced primitive form of the same discriminant $(-8p).$

In either case, the presence of composite numbers represented as $2n^2 + p$ has resulted in $h(-8p) \geq 3,$ contradicting the hypothesis of class number 2.

**Examples for the first case:**

If $p \equiv 3 \pmod 5,$ we can take $n=1$ and get third form
$$  \langle 5,4, \frac{2p+4}{5} \rangle    $$

If $p \equiv 3 \pmod {11},$ we can take $n=2$ and get third form
$$  \langle 11,8, \frac{2p+16}{11} \rangle    $$

**Examples for the second case:**

If $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3,$ we can take $n=1$ and get third form
$$  \langle 3,2, \frac{2p+1}{3} \rangle    $$
If $p \equiv 2 \pmod 5,$ we can take $n=2$ and get third form
$$  \langle 5,2, \frac{2p+1}{5} \rangle    $$

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I will need to work on this a bit, but it is already clear that your condition is that (binary quadratic) form class number $h(-8p) = 2$ for prime $p.$ Note that your $p \equiv \pm 3 \pmod 8,$ otherwise the form $\langle 2,0,p \rangle$ would be in the principal genus, but the presence of two ambiguous forms demands a second genus, therefore the class number would be at least four.

```
Discr  -24 = 2^3 * 3  class  number  2

 all  
      24:  < 1, 0, 6>    Square        24:  < 1, 0, 6>
      24:  < 2, 0, 3>    Square        24:  < 1, 0, 6>


Discr  -40 = 2^3 * 5  class  number  2

 all  
      40:  < 1, 0, 10>    Square        40:  < 1, 0, 10>
      40:  < 2, 0, 5>    Square        40:  < 1, 0, 10>


Discr  -88 = 2^3 * 11  class  number  2

 all  
      88:  < 1, 0, 22>    Square        88:  < 1, 0, 22>
      88:  < 2, 0, 11>    Square        88:  < 1, 0, 22>


Discr  -232 = 2^3 * 29  class  number  2

 all  
     232:  < 1, 0, 58>    Square       232:  < 1, 0, 58>
     232:  < 2, 0, 29>    Square       232:  < 1, 0, 58>
```