# Hint for an Imaginary quadratic field question

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, ideal-class-group

I am kinda stuck and am looking for a hint on how to proceed.

Let $m > 2$ be an integer such that $p = 4m − 1$ is prime. Suppose that the ideal
class group of $L = Q(\sqrt{−p})$ is trivial. Show that if n > 0 is an integer and $n^2+n+m < m^2$,
then
$n^2 + n + m$ is prime.

My thoughts so far are:

let $a=(1+\sqrt{(-p)})/2$ the $O_k= \mathbf{Z}[a]$. Also as the class group is trivial $O_k$ is a UFD.

Also $W=n^2+n+m=(a+n)(\bar{a}+n)$ where $\bar{a}$ is the galois conjugate of $a$.

I want to apply dedekind using $a$ which has minimal polymoial $f(X)=X^2-X+m$. We note for all primes $q$ diving $W$ $f(-n)=W=0 \pmod q$ and so as ideals $(q)=(q, n+a)(q,n+\bar{a})=Q_1 \bar{Q_1}$ by dedekind. We note f is inseparable iff $2(-n)-1=0 \pmod q$.

This is where I struggle to make progress. I want to use the $<m^2$ bound somehow and the fact these ideals are principals but I am not sure how. Any hints?

Comment: see  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289338/is-the-notorious-n2-n-41-prime-generator-the-last-of-its-type/289357#289357  ........  and.........
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2997689/show-that-2n211-and-2n229-generate-primes-for-all-non-negative-integers/2998502#2998502

Comment: Please, avoid chitchatting in your questions. See [How to ask a good question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#31696). I edited your question.

Comment: @jjagmath I think the context of which level and what I am studying is important especially in this area of maths which can go very deep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We note our above analysis shows that if W is composite there's an prime ideal with norm $< m$. But $norm(x+y\sqrt{-p})=x^2+py^2$ which is always greater than $m$ if $|y|>1/2$ and we when we have $y=1/2$ we have $|x|\geq 1/2$ and so the norm is greater than m. And if $y=0$ $x$ is an integer and the norm can never be prime. So there are no (principal) ideals of norm a prime less than m and so we have a contradiction.