# Find the smallest prime number $p$ such that $p\, | \,n^2-n-2023$ for some integer $n$.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Find the smallest prime number $p$ such that $p\, | \,n^2-n-2023$ for some integer $n$.

since $n^2-n =n(n-1)$ is the product of two consecutive integers they must be even so the difference between an even and odd number is always odd so $n^2-n-2023$ is always odd which implies $p$ is not even and the only even prime is $2$ so $p\neq 2$  but after this I do not know what to do please help.

Comment: but n is an integer not natural number

Comment: p would divide n^2-n-2023 irrespective of positive or negative

Comment: Is $n$ a positive integer?

Comment: Trial and error seems to work easily enough.  You've eliminated $p=2$, so what about $p=3$?  Keep going.  Since $7\,|\,2023$ you know the answer must be one of $3,5,7$.

Comment: is there any way to do it without trial and error

Comment: because my teacher did not accept trial and error

Comment: Showing that your answer is minimal will require that you eliminate the smaller ones.  As I say, it's obvious that the answer is one of $3,5,7$ so it's a very simple search.

Comment: $n^2-n-2023 \pmod 3$ seems to be cycling as $3,6,3$. Try $\mod 7$

Comment: I don't mean trial and error by guessing $n$.  Just as you eliminated $p=2$ for all $n$, you have to eliminate $p=3$ for all $n$ (or find an $n$ such that $3$ is a factor).

Comment: This bears much resemblence to the famous "prime generating function" $f(n) = n^2 + n + 41$, which is prime for $n=0, 1, ..., 39.$ (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289338/is-the-notorious-n2-n-41-prime-generator-the-last-of-its-type) In a similar vein, my immediate suspicion is the smallest such $p$ is $p = 2023$ ... but $2023$ isn't prime (divisible by $7$). Still, it's a starting point for stuff to look at.

Comment: $-2023/7=-289 $

Comment: For example $2023\equiv1\pmod{3}$ so you have to determine if $n^2-n-1\equiv0\pmod{3}$ has any solutions.  You have to do a similar thing for $p=5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is 7.

As 2023 is a multiple of 7, it follows that for any $n$ that is a multiple of 7, so
will $n^2-n-2023$ be a multiple of 7. So now it remains to show that $n^2-n-2023$ is not a multiple of 2,3, or 5 for any integer $n$.

However, the prime 5 is not a  multiple for any integer $n$: $2023 \equiv 3 \mod 5$ yet there is no $j \in \mathbb{F}_5$ such that $j^2-j = 3$. This implies that there is no $n$ that satisfies $n^2-n \equiv 3 \mod 5$ [make sure you see why] which implies that there is no $n$ s.t. $n^2-n -2023$ is divisible by 5.

Likewise 3 will not be a multiple for any integer $n$; $2023 \equiv 1 \mod 3$ yet there is no $j \in \mathbb{F}_3 $ such that $j^2-j = 1$. This implies that there is no $n$ s.t. $n^2-n -2023$ is divisible by 3 [make sure you see why].

Meanwhile you can check that $n^2-n-2023$ is always odd for each integer $n$; if $n$ is even it is the sum of two evens and 1 odd, if $n$ is odd it is the sum of 3 odds. This implies that there is no $n$ s.t. $n^2-n -2023$ is divisible by 2.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(n)=n^2-n-2023$ and $f_p(n)=f(n)\pmod{p}$

$\begin{array}{c|cc} 
n & 0 & 1\\  \hline 
f_2(n) & 1 & 1\end{array}$ thus $f_2(n)\neq 0$ and $2$ is not a prime factor of $f(n)$

$\begin{array}{c|ccc} 
n & 0 & 1 & 2\\  \hline 
f_3(n) & 2 & 2 & 1\end{array}$ thus $f_3(n)\neq 0$ and $3$ is not a prime factor of $f(n)$

$\begin{array}{c|ccccc} 
n & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\  \hline 
f_5(n) & 2 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 4\end{array}$ thus $f_5(n)\neq 0$ and $5$ is not a prime factor of $f(n)$

And since $f(1)=-2023=-7\times 17^2$ then $p=7$ is the lowest prime dividing $f(n)$ for some $n$.

Answer (score 0):

$n^2-n-2023$ is odd, so for prime $p$ we have, modulo $p,$ that  $n^2-n-2023\equiv 0\iff 4n^2-4n-8092\equiv 0\iff (2n-1)^2\equiv 8093.$

Now $8093\equiv 2 \mod 3,$ and $2$ is not  the residue$\mod 3$ of a square, so $p\ne 3.$

And $8093\equiv 3 \mod 5,$ and $3$ is not the residue$\mod 5$ of a square, so $p\ne 5.$

Since $8093\equiv 1\equiv 1^2 \mod 7,$ we have  $n=1\implies (2n-1)^2= 1\equiv 8093 \mod 7\implies  n^2-n-2023\equiv 0\mod 7.$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $2023 = 7 \cdot 17^2$

### $p=3$

\begin{align}
   n^2-n-2023 \equiv 0 \pmod 3 \\
   n^2+2n-1 \equiv 0 \pmod 3 \\
   (n+1)^2 \equiv 2 \pmod 3
\end{align}

\begin{array}{|c|cc|}
\hline
  n \mod 3 & 0 & 1,2 \\
n^2 \mod 3 & 0 & 1  \\
\hline
\end{array}
The perfect squares modulo $3$ are $0$ and $1$. So there is no solution.

### $p=5$

\begin{align}
   n^2-n-2023 &\equiv 0 \pmod 5 \\
   n^2+4n+2    &\equiv 0 \pmod 5 \\
   (n+2)^2+3  &\equiv 0 \pmod 5 \\
   (n+2)^2    &\equiv 2 \pmod 5
\end{align}

\begin{array}{|c|ccc|}
\hline
  n \mod 5 & 0 & 1,4 & 2,3 \\
n^2 \mod 5 & 0 &  1   & 4  \\
\hline
\end{array}

The perfect squares modulo $5$ are $0, 1, 4$. So there is no solution.

### $p=7$

\begin{align}
   n^2-n-2023 &\equiv 0 \pmod 7 \\
   n^2-n      &\equiv 0 \pmod 7 \\
   n(n-1)     &\equiv 0 \pmod 7 \\
\end{align}

Clearly $n \equiv 0 \pmod 7$ and $n \equiv 1 \pmod 7$ are solutions.