# Why does this polynomial only generate primes?

Tags: number-theory

I recently saw this polynomial...
$f(x) = x^2+x+27941$

What i found amazing about it that it generates only prime numbers. Here are some first values generated by this polynomial for negative numbers even [image]

I cannot understand why this is happening? Also, i do not think it specifically generates all numbers $\equiv 1,-1 \pmod 6$. Can you please help me? Also, is there any proof of this, that it generates so many primes?

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, i see that this polynomial does not generate a prime for $x=1000000$. Her is the factprization:-
[image]
[image]

Comment: It definitely does not generate only primes; there is a generic method to generate formulas like these that generate ever-so-many primes for the first ever-so-many positive integer inputs (and I guess it could be generalized to the negative like in your case). IIRC Euler talked about it at some point. The details escape me at the moment, but for the sake of a counterexample, take $x=1,000,000$ and it factors: [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factorize+(1000000)%5E2+%2B++1000000+%2B+27941)

Comment: But why does it generate so many primes?

Comment: [Here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html) also seems to be a Math World page on the topic.

Comment: Of course it factors for $x = 27941$, too.

Comment: There is a theorem that no polynomial can generate only primes.

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289338/is-the-notorious-n2-n-41-prime-generator-the-last-of-its-type.

Comment: Not only your polynomial, here is a list of polynomials that generates prime numbers. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html

Comment: @MartinR is there any reason why this is generating primes for so large values?

Comment: @ShamimAkhtar I think you could also ask why the transcendental number $e^{\sqrt{27941}\pi}$ differs by less than $0.03$ from an integer ...

Comment: $x^2+x=x\cdot (x+1)$ has relatively many divisors for small integer $x$, namely all divisors of $x$ and all divisors of $x+1$ (e.g.,it is *always* even and *often* a multiple of $3$). Now if $c$ in $x^2+x+c$ has no small prime factors in that range, then $x^2+x+c$ is already guaranteed to not have those small factors. It might accidentally have some left out small factors, or unusually have only largish prime factors, but the chances are certainly significantly enlarged that $x^2+x+c$ is prime ...

Comment: Moreover, for a prime $p$, $x^2+x$ tends to assume only about half the possible values $\bmod p$ that exist. Hence if $c$ is cleverly chosen, $x^2+x+c$ will never be a multiple of $p$. Do this for several $p$ and you obtain a relatively "good" polynomial - however, you can usually expect $c$ to grow rapidly if you take "too many" $p$ and don't make a "lucky" pick such as $c=41$

Comment: In the range $[-10^6,10^6]$ , this polynomial has a success-ratio $$0.2861$$ about $2$ out of $7$ !

Comment: If $f(x)=x^2+x+n$ for integers $x$ and $n$, then $f(x)$ is always composite if $x=n$; the fact of this matter is that setting $x=n$ yields $f(x)=x(x+2)$.

Answer (score 5):

The statement is false. You can check this without a computer by observing that for $x = 27\,941$ we have $$f(27\,941) = 27\,941^2 + 27\,941 + 27\,941 = 27\,941 (27\,941 + 2) = 27\,941 \cdot 27\,943 ,$$ which is not prime.

**Edit** In fact, consulting a computer shows that the claim fails already for $x = 5$: $$f(5) = 83 \cdot 337 .$$

Comment: That's why $f(x)=x^2+x+41$ is so good, because $f(x)$ is prime for all integers $x\in[0,41)$. I wonder if there exist other polynomials $p(x)=x^2+x+n$ for some integer $n$, given $p(x)$ is prime for $x\in[0,n)$. Of course, $n$ would have to be prime, but would such a $p(x)$ reveal something else about $n$?

Comment: @MrPie  Hugh Williams, Richard Mollin and Gilbert Fung did a bunch of work on this.  It has to do with the discriminant of the polynomial being $-163$ and the ring of integers in $Q(\sqrt{-163})$ having class number one.

Comment: There are, but $41$ is the last such number, which is the content of this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289338/is-the-notorious-n2-n-41-prime-generator-the-last-of-its-type . The discriminant of $x^2 + x + n$ is $1 - 4 p$, and it turns out that the key fact in the case $n = 41$ is that the (negative of its) discriminant $\Delta$ is the Heegner number $163$. Similarly, for $n = 17$, $-\Delta = 67$, the second-largest Heegner number. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number

Comment: (In particular this is indirectly related to the fact that Ramanujan's constant, $e^{\pi \sqrt{163}}$ is extremely close to an integer [a difference of $~10^{-12}$].)

Comment: @Travis Wait, Ramanujan's constant is... *related* to this?? :P

Comment: @B.Goddard I see!

Comment: This is outside my wheelhouse, but both the result in the linked question and the business with Ramanujan's constant are consequences of the fact that the relevant quadratic number field, namely $\Bbb Q\left(\frac{1}{2}(1 + \sqrt{-163})\right)$ has class number $1$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number#Almost_integers_and_Ramanujan's_constant (and the linked post).

Answer (score 1):

plenty of composites

====================

here are some that are not squarefree

```
346    148003  =   47^2 67
364    160801  =   401^2
547    327697  =   67^2 73
658    461563  =   67 83^2
995    1018961  =   89 107^2
```

===================

```
-21    28361  =   79 359
-20    28321  =   127 223
-18    28247  =   47 601
-17    28213  =   89 317
-12    28073  =   67 419
-9    28013  =   109 257
-6    27971  =   83 337
5    27971  =   83 337
8    28013  =   109 257
11    28073  =   67 419
16    28213  =   89 317
17    28247  =   47 601
19    28321  =   127 223
20    28361  =   79 359
29    28811  =   47 613
32    28997  =   107 271
36    29273  =   73 401
42    29747  =   151 197
55    31021  =   67 463
56    31133  =   163 191
58    31363  =   79 397
64    32101  =   47 683
65    32231  =   167 193
72    33197  =   89 373
74    33491  =   107 313
76    33793  =   47 719
77    33947  =   83 409
78    34103  =   67 509
88    35773  =   83 431
99    37841  =   79 479
100    38041  =   109 349
101    38243  =   167 229
105    39071  =   89 439
106    39283  =   163 241
107    39497  =   127 311
108    39713  =   151 263
109    39931  =   73 547
111    40373  =   47 859
117    41747  =   109 383
122    42947  =   67 641
123    43193  =   47 919
127    44197  =   193 229
134    46031  =   191 241
137    46847  =   79 593
139    47401  =   107 443
145    49111  =   67 733
146    49403  =   127 389
154    51811  =   197 263
158    53063  =   47 1129
160    53701  =   83 647
161    54023  =   89 607
170    57011  =   47 1213
171    57353  =   83 691
178    59803  =   79 757
181    60883  =   107 569
182    61247  =   73 839
189    63851  =   67 953
193    65383  =   151 433
194    65771  =   89 739
203    69353  =   223 311
205    70171  =   47 1493
209    71831  =   109 659
212    73097  =   67 1091
216    74813  =   79 947
217    75247  =   47 1601
219    76121  =   163 467
226    79243  =   109 727
232    81997  =   167 491
234    82931  =   127 653
238    84823  =   271 313
239    85301  =   197 433
242    86747  =   223 389
243    87233  =   83 1051
246    88703  =   107 829
247    89197  =   191 467
248    89693  =   257 349
250    90691  =   89 1019
252    91697  =   47 1951
254    92711  =   83 1117
255    93221  =   73 1277
256    93733  =   67 1399
257    94247  =   79 1193
258    94763  =   193 491
259    95281  =   151 631
264    97901  =   47 2083
265    98431  =   257 383
268    100033  =   167 599
269    100571  =   163 617
273    102743  =   127 809
279    106061  =   67 1583
283    108313  =   89 1217
288    111173  =   107 1039
295    115261  =   79 1459
299    117641  =   47 2503
300    118241  =   317 373
303    120053  =   271 443
311    124973  =   47 2659
318    129383  =   109 1187
320    130661  =   193 677
323    132593  =   67 1979
325    133891  =   191 701
326    134543  =   83 1621
328    135853  =   73 1861
330    137171  =   229 599
```