# Form of divisors of Euler's prime generating polynomial

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I found an interesting form of divisors of Euler's prime generating polynomial.

The form is this.
$$
x^2+xy+41y^2
$$

This expression exactly become to Euler's prime generating polynomial when $y=1$.

Do you know something about this form ?

Comment: Have you a reason to think there is anything remarkable about it for values of $y$ other than 1 ? Here's what Wolfram thinks of it https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2Bxy%2B41y%5E2

Comment: It generates a lot of primes since its discriminant is very special: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_number_fields_with_class_number_one  In particular *any* prime $p$ such that $-163$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod{p}$ (so, loosely speaking, half the primes) can be represented as $x^2+xy+41y^2$ for some $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are coprime integers, it is not divisible by any prime $<41$.

Comment: And this is due to the fact that the least odd prime $p$ such that $\left(\frac{-163}{p}\right)=1$ is $41$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two related facts, tied together because of class number one:
if we have odd prime $q$  with Legendre symbol $(-163|q) = -1,$   then
$$ x^2 + xy + 41 y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod q  $$
if and only if
$$  x \equiv y \equiv 0 \pmod q,$$
in which case $x^2 + xy + 41 y^2$ is actually divisible by $q^2.$ The same fact holds for the prime $2$ because $41$ is odd, the form is not even unless both $x,y$ are even.

Next, if you have an odd prime $p$ dividing $x^2 + x + 41,$ it is necessary that either $p=41$ or $(-163|p) = 1.$ This comes from taking $y=1$ in the first paragraph. Oh, of course $x^2 + x + 41$ is odd.

Finally, if $(-163|p) = 1$ or $p=41,$ then $p$ really can be expressed as
$$ p = u^2 + uv + 41 v^2.  $$ That also comes of class number one. There is a simple algorithm based on first solving
$$  \beta^2 \equiv -163 \pmod{4p}$$
or $\beta^2 - 4pt = -163,$ then keeping careful track while Gauss reducing the positive binary form $\langle p, \beta, t \rangle$  to the inevitable $\langle 1,1,41 \rangle$ and inverting a certain 2 by 2 integer matrix.

It was an elementary result of Rabinowitz in 1913 that the polynomial $x^2 + x + p$ with $p$ a positive odd prime, **and form class number one**,  assumes prime values with all integers $0 \leq x \leq p-2.$ I put a proof at

[Is the notorious $n^2 + n + 41$ prime generator the last of its type?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289338/is-the-notorious-n2-n-41-prime-generator-the-last-of-its-type/289357#289357)

It is actually an if and only if result.