$n^2+n+a$ is composite for some $0 \leq n \leq a-2$ if and only if $d=1-4a$ is a square modulo $4p$ for some prime $p<a$.
Let $a \geq 2$. I want to show that $n^2+n+a$ is composite for some $0 \leq n \leq a-2$ if and only if $d=1-4a$ is a square modulo $4p$ for some prime $p<a$.
I've tried considering the binary quadratic form $f(x,y) = x^2+xy+ay^2$ and using results listed below. Note $f(n,1) = n^2+n+a$, and that $\mathrm{disc}(f) = 1-4a=d$.
I know the result that if $d \in \mathbb{Z}$, $d < 0$, $d \equiv 0, 1 \mod 4$, then $m$ is properly represented* by a positive definite binary quadratic form of discriminant $d$ if and only if $d$ is a square modulo $4m$, which appears to be helpful here, as $d=1-4a \equiv 1 \mod 4$.
Also, a binary quadratic form $f$ represents $m$ if and only if $f$ is equivalent to a binary quadratic form $mx^2+bxy+cy^2$.
If a prime is represented by a binary quadratic form, it is properly represented, as if $p=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$, then $(x,y) \mid p$.
I've been playing around with these results for a while but am struggling to apply them here. What can I do?

*If $n$ is properly represented by $ax^2+bxy+cy^2$, I mean that there exists $x,y$ such that $(x,y)=1$, $n = ax^2+bxy+cy^2$.

I put an answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289338/is-the-notorious-n2-n-41-prime-generator-the-last-of-its-type   that goes through the Rabinowitz (1913)  results,  in language that is likely familiar to you.
